# Booting from external drive through USB 3.0 port does freeze keyboard

Tags: boot, grub2, keyboard, peripherals

I have a small netbook for portability and document stuff.
I have tried something on two external disc drives, which result into the same:

- Using USB 2.0 port for DVD drive: Starts normally.
- Using USB 2.0 port for boot media while other device or USB hub is connected USB 3.0 port: same as following:

  - Using USB 3.0 port:
    The keyboard is unresponsive after selecting a boot opion in Grub (UEFI boot, because that laptop denies legacy boot). However, connecting an external **mouse** works. Comnecting an external keyboard also works, but turns the DVD drive from *sr0 into sr1*. Then, I get flooded with SQUASHFS errors of course.

#### What might be the cause? And how can I fix it?

The disc is 100% undamaged, so is the ISO file. Integrity check succeeded.

The same effect also happens on LinuxMint and SuSE. But SuSE does freeze from either port booting.

Comment: My guess would be faulty hardware.

Comment: Simply it may be power issue (USB is isually 500 mA per port, HDD needs about 1 A to spin-up). Try to connect laptop's power adaptor to AC outlet.